# access nested property value using apcahe propertyUtilbean

Tags: java, apache

I am converting json response to Object type using jakson api and after i want to verify the property values .

```
ObjectMapper  mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object jsonobj = mapper.readValue(inputStream,Object.class);
```

i am getting correct mapped json response to Object type .

```
{fatalError=false,messages=[{code=1234,xyz=abcd}]}
```

using PropertyUtilbean class i want to get my object property value
`String val =propertyutil.getProperty(jsonobj,"fatalError")`--- this will give value as false, but if i want to get value using key **messages.[0].code** it is giving me no such method found. please help me out if i am using wrong key format. any help will be appreciated.!

Comment: is there any java version issue ?

Answer (score 0):

this is nested arrayList object and messages is a arrayList ,can you try with index number---- **messages[0]**

Comment: yes i have tried using array index but it is giving me null